# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препенания в прямой речи?

Tags: пунктуация

– Из-за родни? – понимающе уточнил Ёжик. Паук кивнул. – Конечно, можно. Только ты мне поможешь осушить болотце перед крыльцом. Я хотя и болотный Ёжик, но болота обхожу стороной.

Answer (score 2):

– Из-за родни? – понимающе уточнил Ёжик. Паук кивнул. – Конечно, можно. Только ты мне поможешь осушить болотце перед крыльцом. Я хотя и болотный Ёжик, но болота обхожу стороной.

Думаю, что такой вариант более верный. Фраза принадлежит  Ёжику, она разделена на две части словами автора, которые, кроме указания на говорящего, содержат попутное  замечание о реакции Паука на первую фразу.

Answer (score 1):

– Из-за родни? – понимающе уточнил Ёжик. Паук кивнул.  
– Конечно, можно. Только ты мне поможешь осушить болотце перед крыльцом. Я хотя и болотный Ёжик, но болота обхожу стороной.

Если прямая речь оформлена с помощью тире, то надо начинать новую реплику диалога с нового абзаца.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

"Из-за родни? – понимающе уточнил Ёжик. Паук кивнул. - Конечно, можно. Только ты мне поможешь осушить болотце перед крыльцом. Я хотя и болотный Ёжик, но болота обхожу стороной".

Тогда не надо ломать голову, кто сказал последние слова.

Answer (score 0):

В этой конструкции прямая речь прервана словами автора. При этом в словах автора есть два глагола высказывания (один - уточнил, второй подразумевается (кивнул и сказал). По Розенталю, если один из глаголов относится к первой части прямой речи, а второй - ко второй части, то после второго глагола ставится двоеточие и тире.
Таким образом, конструкция должна выглядеть так: "Из-за родни? – понимающе уточнил Ёжик. Паук кивнул: - Конечно, можно..." и т.д.

Comment: Я с вами не соглашусь. В вашем примере вторая фраза принадлежит Пауку, а там сказано: "Я хотя и болотный Ёжик..." То есть её говорит сам Ёжик.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Я не вчитался и подумал, что оба глагола в словах автора относятся к одному и тому же персонажу